# Blazor Hub Does not Connect Across Entire MVC App

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I upgraded an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project to 3.0 in order to use a Blazor component in one of the views of the application. After setting up Blazor in the MVC project and running it, the Blazor hub connects just fine as shown in the browser console screenshot below:

[image]

but when I navigate to the page that contains the blazor component or another page besides the index page for that matter, I get this:

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, it includes the name of the controller the url that negotiates for a websocket connection and throws a 404. If this is not a bug, how can I fix this to work on every view of the application or the view that contains my component to say the least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to set the app base path in shared.chtml and Boom! Problem Solved.

Comment: Set it to what? My project doesn't have a "shared.chtml" do you mean one of the stock cshtml files? Which one?  Can you provide an example? Without knowing what to set it to, this answer is a lot less useful.